# Trigger a specific dialog in Bot via Directline API

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm working on breaking my bot repo into 2 separate repos

1. A repo to purely handle bot logic
2. A repo to handle custom chat via directline

Currently , we have a feature where we can trigger the bot to start a specific dialog if its mentioned as a parameter in the URL. So something like

`https://foo.com/?param=bar`

would trigger the `bar` dialog

This is the code that handles it

function(userId, conversationId, params, token){

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var _directlineAddress = {
            bot: {"id":config.BOT.ID, "name": config.BOT.HANDLE},
            channelId: "directline",
            serviceUrl: config.BOT.DIRECTLINE_URL,
            useAuth: true,
            user:{"id": userId}, 
            "conversation": {"id": conversationId}                                    
        }
        if(params.options){
            var _re = /^\?(\w+)*=(\w+)*/
            var _programType = _re.exec(params.options);

            if (_programType[1] === "foo") {
                var _dialogId = "*:/foo";
            }
            else {
                var _dialogId = "*:/" + _programType[1];
            }

        } else {
            var _dialogId = "*:/";
            var _specialParams = {"sessionId":token};                
        }
        bot.beginDialog(_directlineAddress, _dialogId, _specialParams, function(err){
            else{
                resolve();
            }
        });
    })
};
```

Since i'm splitting the directline from the bot logic , i will no longer be having access to the bot object. therefore `bot.beginDialog` would not work here

Is there a way i can trigger the dialog by posting to the Directline API?

Answer (score 0):

No. With `Direct Line` you will be able to send messages to the bot. I guess that a way to go here will be to define a convention message that you will send via `Direct Line` and that the bot logic will know that it will have to start a dialog based on it.

Comment: Thank you - as i understand , we would need to start a new conversation with the user?